# How to update Google Play Developer API to version 3 on Xamarin Forms App?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

[image]

While uploading new APK to GooglePlay of a very simple APP which using only webview using Visual Studio 2019 Xamarin.Forms i am getting the following error on Google Play console:

> "We’ve detected that your app is using an old version of the Google
>   Play Developer API. From December 1 2019, versions 1 and 2 of this API
>   will no longer be available. Update to version 3 before this date.
>   Learn more"

[image]

[image]

Nuget Packages:

> Id                                  Versions                                 ProjectName
>   --                                  --------                                 -----------
>   Microsoft.AppCenter.Analytics       {2.1.1}                                  xamarin
>   Xamarin.Essentials                  {1.1.0}                                  xamarin
>   Microsoft.AppCenter.Push            {2.1.1}                                  xamarin
>   NETStandard.Library                 {2.0.3}                                  xamarin
>   Microsoft.AppCenter.Crashes         {2.1.1}                                  xamarin
>   Xamarin.Forms                       {4.0.0.540366}                           xamarin
>   Microsoft.AppCenter                 {2.1.1}                                  xamarin
>   Microsoft.AppCenter                 {2.1.1}                                  fms_xamarin.Android
>   Microsoft.AppCenter.Analytics       {2.1.1}                                  fms_xamarin.Android
>   Microsoft.AppCenter.Crashes         {2.1.1}                                  fms_xamarin.Android
>   Microsoft.AppCenter.Push            {2.1.1}                                  fms_xamarin.Android
>   Xamarin.Forms                       {4.0.0.540366}                           fms_xamarin.Android
>   Xamarin.Android.Support.Design      {28.0.0.1}                               fms_xamarin.Android
>   Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCo... {28.0.0.1}                               fms_xamarin.Android
>   Xamarin.Android.Support.v4          {28.0.0.1}                               fms_xamarin.Android
>   Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.CardView {28.0.0.1}                               fms_xamarin.Android
>   Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.Media... {28.0.0.1}                               fms_xamarin.Android
>   Xamarin.Android.Support.Core.Utils  {28.0.0.1}                               fms_xamarin.Android
>   Xamarin.Android.Support.CustomTabs  {28.0.0.1}                               fms_xamarin.Android
>   Xamarin.Essentials                  {1.1.0}                                  fms_xamarin.Android
>   Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Base     {60.1142.1}                              fms_xamarin.Android
>   Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Basement {60.1142.1}                              fms_xamarin.Android

How can i update the SDK as google asking for?

Comment: How are you uploading your package to GooglePlay? CI, or direct upload from the Console?

Comment: I would also like to know the answer for this. For us we are uploading via appcenter.

Comment: @Bruno - uploading using visual studio 2019

Comment: @Umair - upvote 

Comment: @Omtechguy did you found reason and solution for this warning?

Comment: I'm also getting this error. I am signing my APK through Visual Studio and then manually uploading to the developer console.

Comment: Is there any functionality of in app billing in your app?

Comment: We are building our app (Xamarin.Forms 4.1) and publish it to Google Play with Azure DevOps and have the same warning. No in-app billing.

Comment: I'm using VS2019 Mac and uploading using Fastlane, get the same issue

Comment: Archive distribution to Google Play Store via Visual Studio 2019 (v16.3.10) is now fully broken as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59185535/how-do-i-deploy-to-google-store-via-vs-2019-using-version-3-of-the-google-api

Answer (score 1):

Adding this answer for someone that might stumble upon this thread:

This has been fixed in the newest version of Visual Studio 2019, so you just need to update your Visual Studio version to latest.