# How do I Deploy to Google Store via VS 2019 using Version 3 of the Google API

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, deployment, google-play

Up until recently, we've been archiving and deploying to the Google Play store via Visual Studio 2019.  Google recently deprecated v1 and v2 of the deployment APIs.  Now when I try to deploy from VS, it says 'This API has been deprecated and is no longer available. [410]'

[image]

Is there a configuration file somewhere I can use to change to version 3 of the API?  Or is there something in Google Play where I have to create a new set of credentials that specifically targets v3 of the deployment API? We are running 16.4 with all the latest updates.

Comment: Same problem here : https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/844304/api-has-been-deprecated-410.html?inRegister=true

Comment: My team uses jenkins to push our apk to google play store. The API was deprecated December 2nd but we were able to upgrade our jenkins plugin and we can push to the store again

Comment: There seems to be a workaround to publish to the play store, but it requires some manual steps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59164914/how-to-solve-xamarin-forms-api-deprecated-error-410

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update to Visual Studio 16.4.2 and it is now back to working.